# Dell Latitude 7480 heats and freezes on Debian Testing, no clues in the logs

Tags: debian, freeze, fan, intel-graphics

By a "freeze" I mean the system becomes unresponsive (mouse, keyboard, keyboard backlight always on, no `Ctrl+Alt+F1`, no `Ctrl+Alt+Backspace`). I have to hard-shutdown by keeping the power button pressed.

Whenever I've experienced this sort of problem, a kernel upgrade or a BIOS upgrade usally solve the problem. I'm running kernel 5.16.7-2; the BIOS is on the lattest version (1.9.3). I've been able to use the computer for around 2 hours without encountering any freeze, so I thought it was solved. I [even posted a solution to my own question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/693951/debian-testing-freezing-because-of-overheating-fan-sensors-give-confusing-info) on Unix.SE.

The freezes *usually* happen when the computer is charging, but I just had (three minutes ago) to shut it down (fortunately the browser saved most of the text of this question); the uptime was 15 minutes, the laptop is not connected to the power outlet. While I was writing that last sentence, the laptop froze for a total uptime of 4 minutes; I'm writing from another laptop (again, the site saved the draft); this is why I'm almost convinced that it is a temperature issue: the laptop was still quite warm when the last two freezes happened, and they happened in less and less time (so I suspect I didn't give it enough time to cool off).

Besides adding the kernel parameter `acpi_osi=!Windows 2020` (which indeed solves the no-fan problem, but I don't know if it makes it start when it's needed), I added `i915.enable_psr=0`, and created `/etc/modprobe.d/i915.conf` with that exact line in it as per [this solution for a similar laptop model](https://hobo.house/2018/05/18/fix-for-intel-i915-gpu-freeze-on-recent-linux-kernels/) (Latitude 7490). This is the Intel device in question:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 620 (rev 02) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 620
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 134, IOMMU group 1
    Memory at eb000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at a0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at 000c0000 [virtual] [disabled] [size=128K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

The laptop is quite hot when these freezes happen, that is what I first attributed them to the fan not working; I have tested the fan works by issuing `yes > /dev/null` and letting it run for about 30 seconds; the fan starts working at max speed. However, I don't recall hearing the fan start when the system freezes, so perhaps it is related. I don't know what other parameters I should use.

The logs return nothing useful; the system just freezes; no errors, no warnings... nothing; I really mean this: there is nothing in `/var/log/syslog` nor in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` that indicates an error; I'll post a pastebin if necessary (once the laptop cools off), but this hasn't changed. This is very frustrating (and mildly infuriating) because I don't know the cause of the problem.

EDIT: I just reinstalled Debian Stable on it; same problem. This time the screen goes black when the freeze happens. Again, the logs are silent.

Please help me diagnose this!! Is this distro-specific? Is it the fan not kicking in when it should? Thanks!

Comment: What are the results of the built-in diagnostics? Shutdown, hold Fn key then tap power button. Else press F12 repeatedly after powering on to get boot menu then select diagnostics

Comment: Hi @gregg. I have run them before; I did precisely to know whether the fan worked, and it did (at full speed during the memory test). All tests were completed successfully.

Comment: If you think it's CPU heat related you could run a offline/bootable versions of prime95 to see if it locks up there. I use OfflineBootCD, but that requires enable legacy mode in BIOS as it can't handle UEFI last I checked. We're using some process of elimination to determine if it's hardware or possibly the OS

Comment: One of the most puzzling things about this is that I am really not convinced it's CPU heat; it's heat, alright; the bottom of the laptop is quite warm when this happens, but running `watch sensonrs` all temperatures are within "normal" ranges (CPU less than 50, GPU too, for example). I just want to know how to tell the fan to start, and I don't know how to do it. I tried `fancontrol` at some point, but didn't work.

Comment: I can't help with that. However I did see there is a newer BIOS: https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=fw02y&oscode=ub16g&productcode=latitude-14-7480-laptop

Comment: I upgraded the BIOS and I just had another freeze after unplugging it from the outlet; uptime was 1:55. It was charging for the better part of an hour.

Comment: *Maybe* the solution is to add the kernel parameter `intel_idle.max_cstate=0` to `/etc/default/grub`; I'm still running tests with this included.

Comment: Scratch the last comment; minutes after writing it, the laptop froze. :(

Comment: If its under warranty I'd call support. If not it might be a good idea to replace the thermal paste between CPU & heatsink. Also over GPU if you have discrete graphics card (nvidia usually): https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/latitude-14-7480-laptop/latitude_7480_ownersmanual/removing-heat-sink-assembly?guid=guid-8011c9b4-fd16-4fa6-bfd2-7d3f433b65cb&lang=en-us